# jQuery: How to get the closest value when a button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, traversal, closest

I can't seem to get this code to work.
How do I get the closest value of .abc when the button is clicked?

**Defining Closest**

*ie: if you click the button where "A:" is at I want a value of 10.
if you click the button listed in "B:" I want the value of 20.*

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

 $('.test').click(function(){
  var value = $(this)
     .parent()
     .parent()
     .closest(".abc")
     .attr("value")
  alert(value);
  return false
 });

});
</script>
<form name="myform">
<table>
 <tr>
     <td>A:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="abc" name="a" id="a" value="10" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="vbn" id="vbn" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mkl" id="mkl" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="test" name="test" id="test" value="test" /></td>
        <td>B:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="abc" name="b" id="b" value="20" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ews" id="ews" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="hrs" id="hrs" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ew3" id="ew3" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="3ws" id="3ws" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="test" name="test" id="test" value="test" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>C:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="abc" name="c" id="c" value="30" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="oiu" id="oiu" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="dfe" id="dfe" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="test" name="test" id="test" value="test" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>D:</td>
        <td><input type="text" class="abc" name="d" id="d" value="40" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="test" name="test" id="test" value="test" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Please define "closest".

Comment: Please explain the issue a bit more before jumping into the code. Also, could you redefine "closest"?  Did you mean "closets"?

Comment: @Jorn Closest as in close/near.

@Norla, last time I checked my clothes were still in my closet. =]
I was trying to use this expression: http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little while ago, I wrote a plugin which might help in this situation: It's called nextALL.

- [Blog post about it](http://spadgos.com/?p=34)
- [Repostiory Plugin Page](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/nextALL)
- [Demo page](http://fisher.spadgos.com/nextALL.html)

You'd use it like this:

```
$(":button").click(function() {
    $(this).prevALL("td:has(.abc)").eq(0).find(".abc").val();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input.test').click(function() {

    $(this).parent()
           .prevAll('td:has(input.abc)')
           .find('input.abc:last')
           .val();

});
```

Here's a **[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/igadu3)**

Comment: It looks like the problem is A: and B: are in the same row, so clicking that test button always returns the `.abc` value associated with A:

Comment: @fudgey, yeah that solution would be nice... it is so close, yet it is so far away. =/

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the fact that your html code is improperly formatted with multiple elements having the same ID, this javascript code doesn't do what you think it does.  Referring to http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest, `closest()` looks up the tree from where you are.  There is no element matching `.abc` in the tree directly above any of your buttons.  What you're looking for is a neighbor and not a parent.

I would try something like this:

```
$(".test").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().find(".abc").val();
});
```

but it does not solve your issue where multiple .abc near a specific button.

Why not just write the code "correctly" and have a button directly refer to a field using IDs and multiple classes?

Comment: @Brandon, thanks for catching the multiple element with the same ID. I can fix that, but your solution has the same problem as Russ Cam.

Comment: Please see the update to my answer, it provides a valid and corrct solution